# Is this proof about primes correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

We were shown a proof today that supposedy showed that all primes are of the from $6n\pm1$. While I have no issues with this conclusion, and have found valid proofs online, I was unsure as to the validity of the approach given:

To prove by contradiction, we assume that there are primes not of the sequence $6n\pm1$. Take the sequence $6n+3$. Since it contains no primes, we have arrived at a contradiction, therefore the premise is true.

I've given above (restated in my own words) the proof given today. The main issue I have with it is the binary classification of the sequence $6n\pm1$ and all other sequences, and the idea that it is sufficient to prove that $1$ sequence ($6n+3$) contains no primes, to show that all primes are of the sequence $6n\pm1$.

Is my intuition on this correct? Or is this a valid proof? If so, why?

EDIT: Just to clarify, all of the above applies to primes $> 3$

Comment: That is not a valid proof, but then the claim is also false since both $2$ and $3$ are not of the form $6n\pm1$.  Of course these are the only exceptions, but it would be a red flag for any proof not to address these counterexamples either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: Just note that $6n$, $6n+2$, $6n+3$ and $6n+4$ are all composite numbers for $n\ge 1$. So a prime number $\ge 5$ has to be of the form $6n\pm 1$.

Comment: $6n+2$ and $6n+4$ could be considered as one case $6n\pm2$.

Answer (score 2):

An odd number $>3$ can be written in exactly one of the forms $6n-1$, $6n+1$, or $6n+3$. Primes $>3$ are odd, so if it is not of the form $6n \pm 1$, it must be of the form $6n+3$.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a proof, because you are not considering all the cases here.

If you want to prove your statement by contradiction you have consider the cases :

$$6n,$$

$$6n+2,$$

$$6n+3,$$

$$6n+4.$$

This is not much more difficult thant the cases $6n+3$ though (it is the same method each time) but you have to consider those cases anyway.

Comment: Why not also $6n$?

Comment: @ErickWong You are absolutely right, I edited to correct. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the proof is not complete.

He also needs to show that we cannot have prime of the form of $6n$, $6n+2=2(3n+1)$, $6n+4=2(3n+2)$